# The update information is outdated?

Tags: 14.04, updates

I get this error saying,

> The update information is outdated this may be caused by network problems or a repository that is no longer available please update manually by selecting 'show updates' from the indicator menu and watching for any failed repositories

I click show updates and it gives me a warning pop up telling me the computer is updated. I don't know how to remove the red triangle.

Ive tryed to update with `sudp-apt get update` and it gave me the following errors

```
Failed to get ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/…
```

And

```
ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/…
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get update`. Start the command in a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PPA TahuTEK.net PPA Repository](https://launchpad.net/~tldm217/+archive/ubuntu/tahutek.net) has no packages for Trusty, therefore remove the package with the commands below

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:tldm217/tahutek.net
```

Comment: it gives me this 

sudo: ppa-purge: command not found

Comment: Sorry, install it first. I have added the command into y answer.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)